# VBA Script runs alone but not on an active x command button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that I use to search for certain criteria in a the workbook and hide the rows if that criteria is met.  This all works great.  The issue is that I am trying to make a command button for the script and it will not run when using the button.  I am trying to make a sheet with command buttons so I can give the sheet to other people and they can copy it into their workbooks and use the scripts without creating their own modules.

Here is the script I am using:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Rows("1:1000").Hidden = False
    on error resume next

    For Each c In Range("B6:D1000")
        If c.Value <> "Criteria" And c.Value <> "Criteria 1" And c.Value <> "Criteria 2" And c.Value <> "Criteria 3" And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 And c.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" And c.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0 And c.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "" Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
    Next c

Next
starting_ws.Activate
```

The script in its own module works fine.  Only when i past the script into a command button source code does it fail.  It does not give any error messages.  The script looks like it runs through the workbook and then stops on the second page.  I do have "on error resume next" just so it would stop failing on the protected sheet I have toward the end of the work book.  I am going to make a condition to skip protected pages and remove the "on error resume next".  This is something that I will do later.  If i have issues with that I will open a new question.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:

I have made the changes and now the script runs through all the worksheets without error but now it will not actually hide the rows I want hidden.  Here is the code now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next ws

        Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
        Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
        If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                ws.Activate 'Line 12 here

                    Rows("1:1000").Hidden = False

                    For Each c In Range("B6:D1000")
                        If c.Value <> "Criteria" And c.Value <> "Criteria1" And c.Value <> "Criteria2" And c.Value <> "Criteria3" And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 And c.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" And c.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0 And c.Offset(0, 2).Value <> "" Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
                    Next c

                Next
            Else
        End If
        starting_ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Bear with me as I am quite new to VBA.  I am trying to learn it though so constructive feedback it always helpful.  I am still a little confused on the "ws.Activate" part on line 12.  Do I need this portion of the code?  The workbook has fifteen different worksheets that I want it to cycle through. I though I needed "ws.Activate" to start it on the next page.  Is this the case?  Thanks again for all the help.

EDIT:  I changed the code and updated it using PEH's answer

After looking at PEH's comment I looked over my code and altered it.  This is the code I have now and it runs great.  I am not posting it as an answer as there is probably more I can do to clean it up.  here is the code:

Sub HideAllDoubleZeros()
iAnswer = MsgBox("Do you want to run Hide all Double Zeros?" & Chr(10) _
& "Clicking No will cancel the script.", _
vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Hiding Zeros now")
    If iAnswer = vbYes Then
    Dim ws As Worksheet

```
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next ws

        Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
        Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate *'This is Line 16*
        If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then

        Dim c As Variant
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ws.Rows.Hidden = False

            For Each c In Range("B6:D1000")
                If c.Value <> "criteria" _
                    And c.Value <> "criteria1" _
                    And c.Value <> "criteria2" _
                    And c.Value <> "criteria3" _
                    And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 _
                    And c.Offset(0, 1).Value <> vbNullString _
                    And c.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0 _
                    And c.Offset(0, 2).Value <> vbNullString _
                Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True
            Next c
        Else
            MsgBox ws.Name
        End If
        Next
            starting_ws.Activate *'This is Line 38*
ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
End If

Exit Sub
```

End Sub

I added a comment box to ask if they want to run the script just to prevent a accidental click.  I tried to take "ws.Activate" out of line 16 but when I did this I received "Run-time error '1004': Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error".  I also tried to remove "ws.activate" from line 38 but then I received "error 400".  So now i have them back in the script.  Everything is running great now.  Is there anything else you would recommend to clean up the code or make it more efficient?  I am looking to learn more about VBA coding so if you could include comments as to why you would do it like PEH did in his answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and seeing what goes wrong?

Comment: What does "Fail" mean. Does it error? If so, what is the error, which line does it error on?

Comment: ① *"code does it fail"* is the worst error description you can use. It says nothing about what actually happens. You will need to describe what happens instead of what you expected to happen. ② Don't ever use `On Error Resume Next` without a proper error handling. This just hides error messages but errors still occur you cannot see them. Remove that line or implement an error handling instead. ③ Avoid/remove `.Activate` and reference the sheet directly eg `ws.Rows(…)` or `ws.Range(…)`. This way you don't need to remember the active sheet too.

Comment: So.. I guess we are all stuck here, @MikeF. The code looks fine and we don't have enough information about how it's "Failing" to diagnose. I would agree that removing `On Error Resume Next` and rerunning may give some clues that are being otherwise masked by that line. If I had to guess at the problem I would guess that `Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet` is an issue. Is the command button on the sheet that this code acts against? If not then the "ActiveSheet" isn't the one that you are expecting in your code. `starting_ws = Sheets("yoursheetname")` would be a better choice here maybe.

Comment: @JNevill I think `starting_ws` is not the issue here. It looks like he just remembers which sheet was active one so he can activate it in the end again after using `.Activate` in between. Just the variable naming is a bit confusing.

Comment: I think you guys are wasting your time.  He needs to handle errors first.

Comment: @Jaberwocky I don't see why this would need an error handling at all. One should be able to write that stable enough without any error handling. This is just a simple value checking and row hiding. If that throws errors the code is bad. If you write a good code for that you won't need any error handling at all for that.

Comment: @PEH completely agree.

Comment: I added the On Error Resume Next due to a protected sheet in the workbook it kept throwing an error on.  I am fairly new to VBA script, still learning.  I appreciate all the comments.  I will look into implementing some of this as well.  My apologize on the terrible description of failing.  When i run the script it will jump to a page and stop.  If I try it again, it will either jump to the same page and stop or not run at all.  I did add the code to "This Worksheet" in the visual basic editor and assigned the command button the macro instead and it works like that.  I have to save xlsm though

Comment: No, you **must** remove that line **now** not later. This hides all errors not only these on protected sheets. Hiding an error doesn't make it disappear you just don't see the message box. You can't fix errors you don't see! So do the following now: ① Remove that line. ② Remove `.Activate` and reference the sheet directly everywhere eg `ws.Rows(…)` or `ws.Range(…)` ③ use `If ws.ProtectContents = False Then` to check if the worksheet us unprotected. ④ use `ScreenUpdating` outside the loop and turn it true in the end! ⑤ Update the code in your question and tell which errors you get and where.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you start by dealing with errors properly.

Here is some code I use in just about every routine.

```
Sub subName()
    Dim errorPosition as String
    errorPosition = "some descriptive description"
    On Error GoTo Catch
    Err.Clear
Try: 'I know this isn't necessary, but for readability and common practice, I use this.

'Do code stuff

    GoTo Finally 'again, just for readability and common practice.

Finally:
    On Error Resume Next

'do cleanup stuffs

    Exit Sub

Catch:
    msgBox Right(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Len(ThisWorkbook.FullName) - 3) & ", Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
    Resume Finally
End Sub
```

Comment: I would consider this a bit overloaded for the code in the question. Also a generic error catching for the whole procedure is not useful in most cases. Better to write stable code and use error handling very rarely and in individual code sections for specific cases only. Don's see how this would answer the question.

Comment: I appreciate your comments.  In my opinion, it's just good practice to handle errors up front and as a habit.  If he clicks a button and "nothing happens", it could very well be because he is not handling errors properly (using `on error resume next`).

Comment: well he could remove that line completely. He should not need to handle any errors at all. It's always better to write code so that no errors are thrown at all instead of trying to catch them.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I totally agree with that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I still think we're all wasting our time though, considering the OP isn't helping us help him.  lol

Comment: I will remove the line.  I am going to add a condition to skip protected pages to deal with the error.  I just have to figure that out first.  I just have not got that far yet.  I appreciate the error handling sequence though.  It is always helpful to find out better ways to handle errors.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove **all** `.Activate`
2. Reference **all** `Rows` and `Range` directly with the sheet like `ws.Rows`
3. Instead of `Rows("1:1000").Hidden = False` use `Rows.Hidden = False` so you don't need to extend that later when you have more than 1000 rows.
4. Reduce it to one loop only makes it faster.
5. Test every `ws` for protection not only the active one.
6. Remove the `else` part if not needed (see comment).

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'if you turn it false don't forget
                                       'to turn it true in the end!
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'make worksheet visible

        If ws.ProtectContents = False Then
            ws.Rows.Hidden = False 'unhide rows / make all rows visible

            Dim EachCell As Variant
            For Each EachCell In ws.Range("B6:D1000")
                If EachCell.Value <> "Criteria" And _
                   EachCell.Value <> "Criteria1" And _
                   EachCell.Value <> "Criteria2" And _
                   EachCell.Value <> "Criteria3" And _
                   EachCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 And _
                   EachCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> vbNullString And _
                   EachCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0 And _
                   EachCell.Offset(0, 2).Value <> vbNullString Then
                    ws.Rows(EachCell.Row).Hidden = True
                End If
            Next EachCell
        Else
            'here eg give a message when a sheet is protected
            'or do nothing
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for the help!  the comments are incredibly helpful in teaching me more.  I tried the code as was and was not able to get it running.  I did tweak my code from your example and I have a working version now.  I will edit my post.

Comment: @MikeF. I just saw if forgot the `ws` in `Rows(EachCell.Row)` which should be `ws.Rows(EachCell.Row).Hidden = True` of course. my fault.